# VSTA- Deployment group , add new Machines with PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, deployment, azure-devops

I am trying to add machines to Deployment group. I have executed the given Power-Shell script on the Azure host.
* I ticked the "Use the personal token ..." just in case. 
** The script is auto generated by VSTS (azure).

[image]

but the script stops responding after 1 minute or so, as you see in the below image.

FYI:
I'm an admin on the VM as well as in VSTS.

[image]

after a little googling , look like I have to get somewhere like the below picture, but the script doesn't get there.

Notice: I don't get to the below screenshot !
[image]

Comment: What's "the blowing step"? What script are you running? The screenshot doesn't explain what the **problem** is.

Comment: It is not so clear what the problem is, but ... have you marked the use personal token at the screen where the original script appeared?

Comment: Hi Guys
- I just edited the problem to answer your questions.

Comment: Try to download the agent manually `https://starain.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool` and unzip to a folder, then open command prompt as administrator and call `config.cmd --deploymentpool`, then check the result.